# How can I get MS Access to read from a .txt file at certain intervals?

Tags: php, ms-access

I have coded a basic PHP script that collects the data from a few HTML forms and writes it to a text document, and then configured Access to link this text document to a table and import automatically. This all works fine but the problem is that Access seems to be always using this file meaning that my script can't write to it. How can I get Access to check the document every so often, look at what is there and import it without any duplicate data?

Comment: Scheduling activity within Access is not easy but a fairly common topic. What do you mean by 'every so often'? I have a VBScript scheduled in TaskScheduler to run early every morning and execute a procedure in Access.

Answer (score 1):

two ways:

```
Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = "C:\temp\yourfile.txt"
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
Open strFilename For Input As #iFile
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strTextLine
    
Loop
Close #iFile
```

or you can use below code:

```
Dim intFile As Integer
Dim strFile As String
Dim strIn as String
Dim strOut As String

  strOut = vbNullString
  intFile = FreeFile()
  strFile = "C:\Folder\MyData.txt"
  Open strFile For Input As #intFile
  Do While Not EOF(intFile)
    Line Input #intFile, sIn
    If Left(strIn, 7) = "KeyWord" Then
      strOut = Mid(strIn, 8)
      booFound = True
      Exit Do
  Loop

  Close #intFile

  If Len(strOut) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Your Data is " & strOut
  Else    
    MsgBox "Keyword Not Found"
  End If
```

more info . . .[More Info . . .](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/714d453c-d97a-4567-bd5f-64651e29c93a/how-to-read-text-a-file-into-a-string-1line-at-a-time-amp-search-it-for-keyword-amp-data?forum=accessdev)